# Redirecting node.js output to text file using shell script

Tags: node.js, shell

I want to redirect the output of node.js to txt file.I am able to get the output in console for node.js.

Please help me in this issue.

This is the snippet:

```
node.forEach(function(elem)
{
var toString=elem.path.toString;
console.log(toString);
}
```

Output looks something like this

```
ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/components/content/smartcart/deviceselector/cq_editConfig.xml
ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/components/content/smartcart/deviceselector/deviceselector.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.appendFile(__dirname + '/textFileName.txt', toString, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('Hello World > helloworld.txt');
});
```

Comment: Here how to pass my content that is in toString to 'Text to write'

Answer (score 2):

#### Writing a string to a file

If you are just trying to save the output from that one particular function, you can use the `fs` node core module

```
var fs = require("fs");

var output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
    var elem = node[i];
    output += elem.path.toString() + "\n";
}

fs.writeFile("output.txt", output, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("output.txt saved");
});
```

#### Writing all output to a file

If you are trying to capture everything that is logged to a log file, you have a number of options:

1. Use a loggin package such as [`winston.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) which provides ways of writing logs to a specified file
2. On a unix-based system, pipe the output of `node` to a file

   `node my-file.js > output.txt`

Comment: The thing is I just want to run the .js file and the output needs to be stored in a txt file.Thanks anyways as the issue is resolved.